# SQL Query error in PHP

Tags: php, sql, xampp

This is a code for a cafeteria, and this is the login.

```
<?php

$userna = 'root';
$paso = '';
$mach = 'localhost';
$db ='cafeteria';

session_start();

// GET PAGES RECORD FROM LOG TABLE: *********| Only the first time though:
if (isset($_SESSION['log']) != 'logging')
{
    //  Here, just creating a string:
    $pages_record = "";
    $insert_query = '';
    //      Get saved pages from the database:
    $connection = mysqli_connect($mach,$userna,$paso,$db) or die ("Error in log-page script: AB-1 - query: $insert_query." . mysqli_error($connection));
    mysqli_select_db($connection,'cafeteria');

    //      Query string to pull all pages from table record:
    $get_pages_query = "select * from log-page";

    //      Query the database, and save result:
    $query_pages_result = mysqli_query($connection, $get_pages_query);

    //      Check number of results returned:
    $num_of_results = '';
    $num_of_results = mysql_num_rows($query_pages_result);
    if ($num_of_results > 0)
    {
        // Loop through the result array: Each time, one row, and then the next one ...
        for ($row = 0; $row < $num_of_results; $row++ )
        {
            // Getting one row:
            $get_row = mysqli_fetch_array($query_pages_result);
            // Extracting just the page name from the row:
            $one_page = substr($get_row["page"],strripos($get_row["page"],"/") + 1);
            // Adding this page name to the string created previously:
            if ($row == 0)
            {
                $pages_record .= $one_page;
            }
            else 
            {
                $pages_record .= ",".$one_page;
            }           
        }

        // Once all pages have been read and saved to the string
        // now we save it to the session:
        $_SESSION['logpages'] = $pages_record;
        $_SESSION['log'] = 'logging'; // This just tells us, we are logging pages to the database.
    }
    else 
    {
        // There are no pages in the table:
        $_SESSION['logpages'] = "";
        $_SESSION['log'] = 'logging'; // This just tells us, we are logging pages to the database.
    }
}

// Check if page is already in session list.
$pages_array = array();
if (strlen(isset($_SESSION['logpages'])) > 0 )
{
    // string variable that holds all pages separated by commas:
    $pages_string =  $_SESSION['logpages'];

    // creating an Array to hold all pages already logged in server:
    if (strstr($pages_string, ","))
    {
        $pages_array = explode(",", $pages_string);
    }
    else // just means there's only one page in the record
    {
        // so, we push it inside the array.
        array_push($pages_array, $pages_string);
    }

    // current page: [ We are extracting only the page, not the entire url, Exmp: login.php ]
    $current_page = substr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],strripos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],"/") + 1);

    // Check if current_page is in the array already:
    if (!in_array($current_page, $pages_array))
    {
        // IF is NOT in the array, then add it:
        array_push($pages_array, $current_page);

        // Add it to the Session variable too:
        $pages_string = implode(",", $pages_array);

        // Re-save it to SESSION:
        $_SESSION['logpages'] = $pages_string;

        // Now, add it to the database table "log-page""
        $connection = mysqli_connect($mach,$userna,$paso,$db) or die ("Unable to connect!");
        mysqli_select_db($connection,'cafeteria');

        // Query to insert page description into the table:
        // [ date - time - page - user ]
        $insert_query = "INSERT INTO log-page 
            (`date`, `time`, `page`, `user`) VALUES 
            ('".date("Y-m-d")."', '".date("H:i:s")."', '".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."', '".(isset($_SESSION['SESSION_UNAME']))."')"; 
            mysqli_select_db($connection,'cafeteria');

        // INSERTING INTO DATABASE TABLE:
        mysqli_query($connection, $insert_query) or die ("Error in log-page script: AB-2 - query: $insert_query." . mysqli_error($connection));
        // Done!
    }
    else 
    {
        // IF it IS in the list, just SKIP.
    }
}
else 
{
    // means, that there are absolutely no pages saved in the database, basically this is the first log:
    $_SESSION['logpages'] = substr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],strripos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],"/") + 1);    

    // Now, add it to the database table "log-page""
    $connection = mysqli_connect($mach,$userna,$paso,$db) or die ("Unable to connect!");
    mysqli_select_db($connection,'cafeteria');

    // Query to insert page description into the table:
    // [ date - time - page - user ]
    $insert_query = "INSERT INTO log-page 
        (date, time, page, user) VALUES 
        ('".date("Y-m-d")."', '".date("H:i:s")."', '".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."', '".(isset($_SESSION['SESSION_UNAME']))."')"; 
    mysqli_select_db($connection,'cafeteria');
    // INSERTING INTO DATABASE TABLE:
    mysqli_query($connection,$insert_query) or die ("Error in log-page script: AB-2 - query: $insert_query." . mysqli_error($connection));
    // Done!    
}

?>
```

But now i am getting this error:

> Error in log-page script: AB-2 - query: INSERT INTO log-page (`date`,
>   `time`, `page`, `user`) VALUES ('2012-10-16', '16:58:44',
>   '/caf/pages/index.php', '').You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near '-page (`date`, `time`, `page`, `user`)
>   VALUES ('2012-10-16', '16:58:44' at line 1

Im using Xampp 1.8.1 PHP: 5.4.7. It does not let me login neither as administrator nor as a cashier

Comment: Try `\`date\`` instead of `date`. Use quotes. Date is a spec. word in MYSQL.

Comment: Is your user filed allow null ? And for xampp, did you change root password and can't log in to phpmyadmin ?

Comment: No it does not allow user null. Root password is blank

Answer (score 5):

Enclose the table name in backticks like this (rest of the query omitted):

```
$insert_query = "INSERT INTO `log-page` (`date`, `time`, `page`, `user`) ... ";
```

Otherwise MySQL will try to interpret the `-` as a minus sign, which fails in this case.

**EDIT**

IN the last insert shown, also the column names should be enclosed in backticks:

```
$insert_query = "INSERT INTO `log-page` (`date`, `time`, `page`, `user`) VALUES ...";
```

Comment: Yep, the dash isn't valid in column names and thus it must be enclosed in backticks…

Comment: I did it, now i have this problem Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\caf\pages\log.php on line 47

Comment: @jjumar Looks like the same error in another query: Add backticks here around `log_page` as well: `$get_pages_query = "select * from log-page";`

Comment: @jjumar Add a statement like this after the query with brings you the parameter in the respective `mysql_num_rows()`: `if ( mysql_error() ) { echo mysql_error(); }`. Then have a look at the error message and act accordingly. I wont debug all your script here in the comments, though.

Comment: @Sirko the problem right now is on the parameter of mysql_num_rows... it seems as if $query_pages_result is not giving me a boolean or numeric result

Comment: @jjumar It is giving you probably a boolean `false` as the query fails. so add an output for the error!

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping field name

```
(`date`, `time`, `page`, `user`)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I looked at mySql docs, but it looks to be complaining about the table name "log-page". Try quoting that table name.

Comment: I did it, now i have this problem Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\caf\pages\log.php on line 47